# Why is the Direct3D image overlapped, while be rotated at certain angle range?

Tags: c++, rotation, direct3d

I am a newer for Direct3D that am getting a very weird problem that, my Direct3D image is ok in some rotation range, but seems to be overlapped in the other rotation range. as below images.

Could someone help me to check what's wrong within my code?

thx a lot in advance.

[a part of the image gets problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjBNj.png)

I attached my full project here:
[The source code and the .exe could be gotten here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c2bWWYs)

Comment: It looks like two planes intersect. It is overlapped because it is under/behind the black plane.

Comment: What version of Direct3D are you using?

Comment: I am using DirectX 12, tested on other version also with the same result gotten. Actually I draw only one object and all the height value is positive, that means there is nothing really under/behind the black plane (black plane is also a part of this single object, while the height is 0.) Thx a lot for your help.

Comment: Looks like [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) to me.